# Get the class of <body> using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this AJAX code:

```
function ajax(){
    if (!navigator.standalone) return;
    for (var i= document.links.length; i-->0;) {
        document.links[i].onclick= function() {
            if(this.getAttribute("class") == "noeffect") return;
            var req= new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange= function() {
                if (this.readyState!==4) return;
                document.body.innerHTML= this.responseText;
                ajax();
            };
            req.open('GET', this.href, true);
            req.send();
            return false;
        };}
    }

window.onload= function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0.9);
    ajax();

};
```

Now on my pages I have classes on my `<body>` on certain pages. Only those classes do not get returned of course. 
Is there a way to get the ENTIRE body using AJAX? or maybe the entire html (with the `<head>` content).

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem is that innerHTML sets the HTML inside an element, and doesn't replace it.
So you will at least get a body-element inside a body-element, what is illegal.

So you had to use replaceChild instead of innerHTML, but you can't, because you don't have an body-node, and furthermore I'm afraid that it did'nt work to replace a body-element at all(at least in IE).

responseXML(if available) also will not help you in this case, because you cannot move nodes between different documents in IE

**conclusion:**
You'll need to parse the response, extract the contents of the body and the class of the body.
Then set the innerHTML and the class of the existing body.

Short example(maybe the RegExp needs to be modified depending on the response)

```
var parsed=this.responseText.match(/<body\s+class="([^"]*)">(.*)<\/body>/);
   document.body.className=parsed[1];
   document.body.innerHTML=parsed[2];
```

Comment: uhm eh ok. how? :'(. This seems kinda hard doesn't it :p

Comment: Doesn't have to be difficult, a single RegExp could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [responseXML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started#Step_4_.e2.80.93_Working_with_the_XML_response) instead.

edit.

Your code is incorrect. You should check if `req.readyState==4` and `req.status==200`, then call `req.responseTxt`:

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
    document.body.innerHTML= this.responseText;
    ajax();
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks :). but eh how would I use that? sorry my JavaScript skills are like 1/100

Comment: HTML document = XML document, so you can load it and use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM functions.

Comment: "Use responseXML instead", then your example does not use it at all.

Comment: @atlavis: HTML documents are _not_ XML documents. XHTML documents are XML documents. (And XHTML is dead as of HTML5.)

Comment: if HTML doc body is valid XML, then why not?

Comment: SnippetSpace wants `maybe the entire html (with the <head> content).`, so I suggest `responseXML`.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal — for a value of dead equal to [no more then it has been for the past decade](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#the-xhtml-syntax)

Comment: @Quentin: You'd prefer "socially deprecated"? :)